# Sending a validation email to new registered users to activate their accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

in asp. net web api i am trying to send confirmation mail to new registered user that have a link when click they activate their account i have managed to send email through  SmtpClient and NetworkCredential class but how i would implmint the activation part i do not want to use identity 2. her is the code for sending email.

```
public bool SendMail()
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            string strMessageBody = MailBody;

            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strMessageBody);

            msg.To.Add(MailTo);

            if (MailCC != null && MailCC.Length > 0)
            {
                msg.CC.Add(MailCC); ;
            }
            if (MailBCC != null && MailBCC.Length > 0)
            {
                msg.Bcc.Add(MailBCC);
            }

            //msg.Sender = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailFrom);
            msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(MailFrom);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = strMessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(_strSMTPServer);
            //EmailContent c = (EmailContent)content;
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
            NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new NetworkCredential();
            basicAuthenticationInfo.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"].ToString();
            basicAuthenticationInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
            mailClient.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"].ToString();
            mailClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"].ToString());
            mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailmessage = msg;
            mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            mailmessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mailmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mailClient.Send(mailmessage);
            return true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before sending the email create authentication token for the user and add it to the activation link as additional parameter. In action that is fired by that link you can simply check the token and activate the user if it's correct, or pass token to login view, store it in hidden field and check it after POST together with username and password. Personally, I prefer the second option.

The token could be generated in few ways. For example, by creating hash of some (or all) data given by user, like username + password + registration date. Then, in token's validation you can check if it is equal to token stored in database for this user or (if you don't want to store it) to hash generated in this way again during the validation. If both username + password combination and the token are correct, you can set this user's account to active and allow logging in.

BTW, you have two variables of type `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` - `msg` and `mailmessage` and I think using only one will be good enough.

Comment: Hidden Field should be in email body that contains token?